# hosting server config issue in yii

Tags: php, yii

i implemented my project in Yii framework and uploaded into server. i uploaded successfully. when i run my project i am facing the warning which shown below. i uploaded Yii folder and my project assests, protected, css,images then index.php..

```
Warning: require_once(/home/rainbowp/public_html/../yii/framework/yii.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/rainbowp/public_html/index.php on line 12

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/rainbowp/public_html/../yii/framework/yii.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/rainbowp/public_html/index.php on line 12
```

please suggest how config in server ie index.php  file

Comment: in `index.php` file, you must point to location of framework

Answer (score 2):

You will need to point to the yii.php file correctly in your index.php

```
<?php
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/yii/framework/yii.php';
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL', 3);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
```